# Silverlight 5 Events

Tags: vb.net, silverlight

I am written in Silverlight 5 with VB.Net. I have a number of child windows. I want to catch the event when the user closes this window without clicking on any button. Please give me an example if possible. I prefer VB but I can translate C#.

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to the Closing or Closed Events of you ChildWindows, in the Closing event you can check the DialogResult to see if it is True, if so let the Window Close otherwise Cancel the closing of the ChildWindow by setting e.Cancel to True. The example that I have here shows both events and will allow you to stop the ChildWindows Close.

```
Partial Public Class MainPage
    Inherits UserControl
    Dim child As ChildWindow1

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        child = New ChildWindow1
        AddHandler child.Closed, AddressOf ChildClosed
        AddHandler child.Closing, AddressOf ChildClosing
        child.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ChildClosed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim result As Boolean? = CType(sender, ChildWindow).DialogResult

        If IsNothing(result) Then
            'Do something if DialogResult is Nothing You can not cancel close with this event
        ElseIf Not result Then
            'Do what you want when the Cancel Button is clicked
        ElseIf result Then
            'Do what you want when the Ok Button is clicked
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ChildClosing(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
        Dim result As Boolean? = CType(sender, ChildWindow).DialogResult

        If IsNothing(result) Then
            e.Cancel = True 'This will cancel the ChildWindows Close and leave it open
        ElseIf Not result Then
            'Do what you want when the Cancel Button is clicked
        ElseIf result Then
            'Do what you want when the Ok Button is clicked
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Mark. This doesn't seem to quite solve my problem. I actually want to program an event within the child window.  I will edit and clarify my original question.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer because you me off in the right direction. What I actual needed was to add this to my child window in the New event  AddHandler Me.Closing, AddressOf ClosingEvent